# Initial ViewController with Firebase bug fix

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uiviewcontroller

I've strange bug I cannot understand how to solve. When I set which ViewController should be opened depends if users is registered and I put this code in SceneDelegate I get black screen for a moment before appearing ViewController

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

    class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
        var window: UIWindow?
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
    
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
            guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
            window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
            window?.windowScene = windowScene
    
            if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                FirestoreService.shared.getUserData(user: user) { (result) in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let muser):
                        let navigationController = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Navigation") as! UINavigationController
                        let conroller = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! MainController
                        navigationController.viewControllers = [conroller]
                        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
                    case .failure(_):
                        let conroller = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpController") as! SignUpController
                        self.window?.rootViewController = conroller
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print(3)
                let conroller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpController") as! SignUpController
                self.window?.rootViewController = conroller
            }
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

[image]

But when I put code for appearing ViewController outside the firebase it works as it should. How this can be fixed?

Comment: Thats because `FirestoreService.shared.getUserData` is an asynchronous call, it executes your closure which updates the root view controller asynchronously hence till the time your control comes back to closure and sets the root view controller you see a glitch (a black screen) Rather have a spash screen kind set up (basically set a view controller showing either app logo or some fancy image) in its view did load call this `FirestoreService.shared.getUserData` and once you recieve the closure change root view controller with some fancy animation, search change root view controller with anima

Comment: And how this can be fixed? I don't want to show black screen.

Comment: read the comment again :)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand where I should put the code with spash screen? May be you can provide more detailted instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 ways to solve this issue.

#### 1. Using a splash screen:

Don't make the decision of showing a login screen or main screen in `scene(_:, session, connectionOptions)`. Instead, create a new view controller called `SplashScreenViewController`. Set your app's logo in its center. And then in its `viewDidLoad()` move your logic to check if the user is already logged in:

```
func chooseAndPresentStartScreen() {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        FirestoreService.shared.getUserData(user: user) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let muser):
                let navigationController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Navigation") as! UINavigationController
                let conroller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! MainController
                navigationController.viewControllers = [conroller]
                self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            case .failure(_):
                let conroller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpController") as! SignUpController
                self.present(conroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    } else {
        print(3)
        let conroller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpController") as! SignUpController
        self.present(conroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

#### 2. Using User Defaults:

Define a global variable for the key used to save user default value.

```
let isUserLoggedInKey: String = "IsUserLoggedIn"
```

After the user logs-in:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.setValue(true, forKey: isUserLoggedInKey)
```

Then in your `scene(_:, session, connectionOptions)`, check if this value is set.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let isLoggedIn = defaults.bool(forKey: isUserLoggedInKey)
    if isLoggedIn {
        
        let navigationController = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Navigation") as! UINavigationController
        let conroller = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! MainController
        navigationController.viewControllers = [conroller]
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        
    } else {
        let conroller = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpController") as! SignUpController
        self.window?.rootViewController = conroller
    }
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

Don't forget to set `isLoggedInKey` to false when the user logs out.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.setValue(false, forKey: isUserLoggedInKey)
```

If you don't want to manually save value for `isUserLoggedInKey` when the user logs in and logs out, you can also use a state change listener. It takes a callback that is triggered when the user logs in or logs out. Add this in your Login view controller:

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in 
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.setValue(user != nil, forKey: isUserLoggedInKey)
}
```